# ¿Cómo soluciono este error que de repente hizo que mi página desapareciera?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Me encontraba configurando unos `plugin` en mi nueva página cuando de repente me apareció un anuncio como este, pero de otro `plugin`, se me ocurrió entrar al `cpanel` y borrar el `plugin` directamente desde ahí, otras veces me ha funcionado, pero ahora me sale este error y no tengo ni idea de programación, ¿alguien sabe cómo se puede solucionar?

> Warning: require_once(/home/user/public_html/mipagina.com/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/mipagina.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/init.php on line 107
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/user/public_html/mipagina.com/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/user/public_html/mipagina.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/init.php on line 107

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Revisa el siguiente script, y en la **línea 107** borra el llamado al *plugin*.

```
/home/user/public_html/mipagina.com/wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/init.php
```